# Display error with Visual Studio Code under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl-es, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code for several days: it is impossible to launch it (in fact, the window is almost totally black), and here is the console output when I start it from a terminal:

```
bash: impossible de régler le groupe de processus du terminlal (-1): Ioctl() inapproprié pour un périphérique
bash: pas de contrôle de tâche dans ce shell
[3267:0609/135005:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(361)] [.CommandBufferContext.Compositor-0xc0a90cb29a0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:texture_manager.cc(2278)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderCompositor-0x29650b4d9c60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glTexImage2D: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2113)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : ScopedTextureBinder::ctor: was unhandled
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : ScopedTextureBinder::dtor: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : ScopedTextureBinder::dtor: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : ScopedTextureBinder::dtor: <- error from previous GL command
[3267:0609/135007:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0x29650b4d96e0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : ScopedTextureBinder::dtor: <- error from previous GL command
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu inside virtualbox by any chance?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But it worked well a few days earlier.

Comment: In case anyone else is having the same problem... The issue lies with virtual box guest additions. Installing version  5.0.16 from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads solves the issue.

Comment: I confirm that installing VBox additions v. 5.0.16 solves the issue.

Comment: I can also confirm that the VBox additions 5.0.16 solved the issue. Had a Ubuntu 16.04 guest installed with vbox guest additions 5.0.24 and only got black screen. After rolling back to the 5.0.16, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem and installing virtualbox guest additions version 5.0.16 really solved the problem. However, as noted in the [FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/faq) section of VS Code project web site, you can also run the VS Code with `--disable-gpu` option, which also solves the problem. From the official FAQ :

> VS Code main window is blank?
>
> The Electron shell used by Visual Studio Code has trouble with some GPU (graphics processing unit) hardware acceleration. If VS Code is displaying a blank (empty) main window, you can try disabling GPU acceleration when launching VS Code by adding the Electron --disable-gpu command line switch.

Comment: add `alias code='code --disable-gpu'` to `~/.bashrc` to automate this.

Comment: Or disable 3D acceleration in the Vagrantfile. For example: `vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--vram', '256', '--accelerate3d', 'off']`. See [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d) and [that](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm3517).

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu first try to run visual studio code from terminal with:

```
code
```

If there is any package error install it. Then if there is black screen then go to :

```
sudo vi /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

**Add disable gpu line to following:**

```
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --disable-gpu %U
```